# Initializing global variable class

Tags: c++, class

Apologies for such a basic question but I can't figure it out. I know you can initialize a class like this:

```
QFile file("C:\\example");
```

But how would you initialize it from a global variable? For example:

```
QFile file; //QFile class

int main()
{
    file = ?? //need to initialize 'file' with the QFile class
}
```

Comment: Global variables are a bad idea, by the way.

Comment: You don't initialize a class, you initialize an instance. And please think about why you would need a global variable in the first place, because commonly, you don't.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### 1. Straightforward answer

If the class is assignable/copy constructible you can just write

```
QFile file; //QFile class

int main()
{
    file = QFile("C:\\example");
}
```

#### 2. Use indirection

If not, you'll have to resort to other options:

```
QFile* file = 0;

int main()
{
    file = new QFile("C:\\example");

    //
    delete file;
}
```

Or use `boost::optional<QFile>`, `std::shared_ptr<QFile>`, `boost::scoped_ptr<QFile>`  etc.

#### 3. Use singleton-related patterns:

Due to the [Static Initialization Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) you could want to write such a function:

```
static QFile& getFile()
{ 
    static QFile s_file("C:\\example"); // initialized once due to being static
    return s_file;
}
```

C++11 made such a function-local static initialization thread safe as well (quoting the C++0x draft n3242, §6.7:)

[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as `std::scoped_ptr`, Mr I-look-like-30k ;-)

Comment: Shute :) I was typing `boost::shared_ptr`, edited to `std::shared_ptr`, then thought better of it and changed to `scoped_ptr` :) Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: +1 for covering number of solutions and aspects. Citation or paragraph number to the referenced spec in C++11 would be nice.

Comment: @mloskot: standard reference added

Comment: @sehe Hehe, big effort, thanks. Paragraph number would do well too.

Comment: @sehe You somehow got every sane-ish option except using the same exact syntax in the global scope.

Comment: Static Initialization Fiasco link is dead (July 2015): This one seems to work: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html

Answer (score 4):

The same way:

```
// file.cpp

QFile file("C:\\example");

int main()
{
  // use `file`
}
```

The constructors of all global objects execute before `main()` is invoked (and inversely for destructors).

Comment: Which is the correct answer (for non C++1y). If you have no trivial initializer for the class, then this is the only possible way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
struct QFile
{
    char const* name;
    QFile(char const* name) : name(name) {}
};

QFile file("test.dat"); // global object

int main()
{
    std::cout << file.name << std::endl;
}
```

By the way, you wrote:

> I know you can initialize a class

You can not initialize a class. You create and initialize object, not a class.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally up to you to decide whether you use a global variable or some thing else.

For a global variable you can define it in globally in the file and then initialize it in function as below, make sure that you write copy constructor properly.

```
QFile file; //class object

int main()
{
    file = QFile("C:\\example"); //create a temporary object and copy it to `file`
}
```

But, it is better if you use global pointer,

```
QFile *file;

int main()
{
    file = new QFile("C:\\example");
}
```

Note, if you are using this global variable only within the file, you can make it a `static` variable. Then it is limited to file itself. So you can minimize the **bad** of global variables.